# Webview in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

I'm currently developing a Chrome Packaged App and I'm using webviews, however I'm not having success at hidding the scroll bar on said webviews. I've tried using the overflow tag with no success.

Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: By "overflow tag" I assume you mean something like `overflow: hidden` in the CSS? Show a snippet of what exactly you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var appWin = null;

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'main.html',
    {bounds: {width: 800, height: 400}},
    function(win) {
      appWin = win;
      win.onBoundsChanged.addListener(onBoundsChanged);
      onBoundsChanged();
    }
  );
}

function onBoundsChanged() {
  var bounds = chrome.app.window.current.getBounds();
  var webview = appWin.contentWindow.document.getElementById("#my_webview");
  webview.style.height = bounds.height + 'px';
  webview.style.width = bounds.width + 'px';
}
```

Obviously, if your window is fixed size (resizable: false), you don't need to define an onBoundsChanged handler: you can adjust your webview size directly in the chrome.app.window.create() callback using the hardcoded dimensions you've specified for your window.

Comment: I'm not creating a single webview with the same size of the app window. I'm creating a fullscreen chrome app window, with a blank html page and injecting a couple of webviews into the page through a script. Here's an example of a webview element ready to receive the parameters and to be injected into the html page:

"<webview id=\""+id+"\" partition=\"p_"+id+"\" src=\"" + src + "\" style=\"position: absolute; top:" + top + "px; left:" + left + "px; width:" + width + "px; height:" + height + "px;\"></webview>"

I need to remove the scroll bar on these webviews.

Comment: Can you then calculate the exact dimensions you'd want to allocate to each of your webviews based on the screen size (or app's window size, or their parent element's size) and set them in `chrome.app.window.create` listener? If you need their parent element's size for that, you should additionally wait for `win.contentWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` before trying to `win.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#your-parent")`. Alternatively, just put all the querySelector- and webview- related code into a separate script and include it from `main.html` - that will work too.

Comment: My question wasn't exactly how to dinamically create webviews, but how to hide the scroll bar on the pages loaded inside those webviews. Anyways, I've solved the problem by injecting the necessary css to the webviews triggered by a content loaded event tied to the webview.

Comment: @user2958009 could you please post an answer explaining details of your solution? I'm facing similar problem in my project. Your approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to remove the webview's scrollbar when embedded inside Packaged Chrome App:

```
<html lang="en" style="overflow:hidden">
```

Edit: This code lives inside the page that the webview references - not the code inside your packaged chrome app.